# What package should I install instead of libpcre++-dev to use C code in Alpine Golang?

Tags: docker, go, pcre, alpine-linux, cgo

I have a Golang program inside a docker container (I use Ubuntu 18). Also I use [github.com/glenn-brown/golang-pkg-pcre/src/pkg/pcre](http://github.com/glenn-brown/golang-pkg-pcre/src/pkg/pcre) for regex in my Golang app. Before using this library I should install `libpcre++-dev` this way:

> sudo apt-get install libpcre++-dev

But I use golang:alpine in my Dockerfile and this is no `libpcre++-dev` library in alpine packages.

**What package should I install instead of** `libpcre++-dev`?

p.s. I have tried to install `libc6-compat`, `pcre pcre-dev`, `libpcrecpp` but I see this error:

> github.com/glenn-brown/golang-pkg-pcre/src/pkg/pcre
>   /go/pkg/mod/github.com/glenn-brown/golang-pkg-pcre@v0.0.0-20120522223659-48bb82a8b8ce/src/pkg/pcre/pcre.go:52:10:
>   fatal error: pcre.h: No such file or directory  #include 
>             ^~~~~~~~ compilation terminated

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:alpine

RUN apk update
RUN apk upgrade
RUN apk add --update --no-cache build-base gcc g++ pcre pcre-dev libc6-compat

# Install git + SSL ca certificates.
# Git is required for fetching the dependencies.
# Ca-certificates is required to call HTTPS endpoints.
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache curl git ca-certificates tzdata \
 && update-ca-certificates 2> /dev/null || true
```

I build my app this way:

```
- CGO_ENABLED=1 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -a -installsuffix cgo -ldflags="-w -s" -o bin/backend ./cmd/backend/main.go
```

**EDIT**

I have change my Dockerfile (add line below)

`RUN apk add --update --no-cache build-base gcc g++ pcre pcre-dev libc6-compat`

And now I have a new error:

> Error loading shared library libpcre.so.1: No such file or directory
>   (needed by /bin/backend)

Comment: `RUN apk add --virtual build-dependencies
RUn apk add --no-cache build-base gcc` try this or you can install the alpine sdk `apk add --update alpine-sdk`

Comment: @Adiii On last step (deploy to server) I have an error [20278] INTERNAL ERROR: cannot create temporary directory!

Comment: does the above solve the issue?

Comment: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3262

Comment: @Adiii I have fixed `[20278] INTERNAL ERROR: cannot create temporary directory!` but I still get `github.com/glenn-brown/golang-pkg-pcre/src/pkg/pcre /go/pkg/mod/github.com/glenn-brown/golang-pkg-pcre@v0.0.0-20120522223659-48bb82a8b8ce/src/pkg/pcre/pcre.go:52:10: fatal error: pcre.h: No such file or directory #include ^~~~~~~~ compilation terminated`

Comment: you can ask another question this is different issue

Comment: @Adiii It is not a different problem. I have the same error message as I had before

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199765/discussion-between-adiii-and-klimbo).

Comment: https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages might be a good starting point to try to find packages; there's a link from the [Docker Hub `alpine` image page](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine/).

Comment: @DavidMaze I know this site and I have tested a lot of packages but all of them does not work

Answer (score 3):

You can try one of these, as both package

```
RUN apk add --virtual build-dependencies 
RUn apk add --no-cache build-base gcc
```

> build-essential is a metapackage (a package that installs many other
>   packages, like g++ and gcc: the GNU C & C++ compilers).

Or you can install the alpine sdk.

> You can start with alpine-sdk, which is a "metapackage that pulls in
>   the most essential packages used to build new packages."
>   http://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Developer_Documentation has more
>   info.

```
RUN apk add --update alpine-sdk
```

[docker-alpine-issues-24](https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/24)

Or you can use golang:latest which will work fine.

```
FROM golang:latest
RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get install libpcre++-dev -y
```

Comment: I have an error: Error loading shared library libpcre.so.3

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the Debian-based `golang` images instead.  By the time you're installing GNU libc and a full C toolchain on top of this anyways, there's not really going to be much space savings over the Alpine base image.  You can (and should) use a multi-stage build where the final image just contains your compiled binary, and that can use an Alpine base.

The result would look something like:

```sh
# Build-time image; just has the parts needed to run `go build`
FROM golang:1.12-buster AS build

# Install additional build-time tools
RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install --assume-yes \
      build-essential ca-certificates git-core tzdata \
      libpcre++-dev

# Build your application
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
ENV GO111MODULE=on
RUN go build -o myapp ./cmd/myapp

# Runtime image; has only what we need to run the application
FROM alpine:3.10
# Note that you'll need the shared library for libpcre++
RUN apk add ca-certificates tzdata libpcrepp
COPY --from=build /app/myapp /usr/bin/myapp
CMD ["myapp"]
```

Comment: I have an error: Error loading shared library libpcre.so.3